# Automatically get logged in user's username in Name field of html form

Tags: php, html

Currently users logged in have to type their name manually to comment or post but i want to 
get the username in the field name of html form inserted automatically. Also at the same time user cannot change the name field.

how can i create such session in username field, i tried but code isnt working..

[like this](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/5544/55316393.jpg)

```
//create the form to submit comments
//you can add more fields, but make sure you add them to the db table and the page, submitcomment.php
    echo "
<a name=\"post\">
<div id=\"submitcomment\" class=\"submitcomment\">
<form name=\"submitcomment\" method=\"post\" action=\"submitcomment.php\" onSubmit=\" return form_Validator(this)\">
<table width=\"100%\">
        <tr>
                <th colspan=\"2\"><h4><span>Leave your comment:</span></h4></th>
        </tr>
```

> ```
>               <th scope=\"row\"><p class=\"req\">Name:</p></th>
>               <td><input type= class=\"form\" tabindex=\"1\" id=\"name\" name=\"name\" /></td>
>       </tr>
> ```

```
        <tr>
                <th scope=\"row\"><p class=\"opt\">Email:</p></th>
                <td><input class=\"form\" tabindex=\"2\" id=\"email\" name=\"email\" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

                <th scope=\"row\"><p class=\"opt\">URL:</p></th>
                <td><input class=\"form\" tabindex=\"3\" id=\"url\" name=\"url\" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign=\"top\">
                <th scope=\"row\"><p class=\"req\">Comments:</p><br /></th>
                <td><textarea class=\"formtext\" tabindex=\"4\" id=\"message\" name=\"message\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"50\"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>    
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"post\" class=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Comment\" /><br />
                <p>Note:  Emails will not be visible or used in any way, and are not required.  Please keep comments relevant. Any content deemed inappropriate or offensive may be edited and/or deleted. </p>
                <p>In Beta Phase</p>

</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"tuturl\" value=\"$tuturl\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"tutid2\" value=\"$tutid2\" />
</form>


</div>
";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you telling us or asking us? Please edit your question so that it actually contains a question. Also, don't insert massive code blocks without telling us what part of it that needs attention, and what you have tried to make it work. This is not a "fix this please" community.

Comment: @Alasjo sorry its my first post here... i have made it short..

Comment: No problem, you are here to learn.

Comment: try to clear your basics using w3schools PHP tutorials... you will get your answer easily. then come here if you not get solved

Comment: I would disagree with that schools site, just Google w3fools and you'll see why. The site is just littered with bad and wrong advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

// after user logs in successfully

$_SESSION['username']=$username;

// to read it
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
// then store $username in database when inserting comment

?>
```

Comment: @Aamir what does this return: echo $_SESSION['username']; Did you set up the session after login?

Comment: No, i have a session in page(home.php) and this  comment page is linked with that page(home.php#post) but i have not created session in comments page

Comment: @Aamir print_r($_SESSION); what does this return on comment page?

Comment: i havnt tried it yet,
<th scope=\"row\"><p class=\"req\">Name:</p></th>
              <td><input type= class=\"form\" tabindex=\"1\" id=\"name\" name=\"print_r($_SESSION)\" /></td>

Comment: @Aamir use name=\"echo $_SESSION)['username'] instead of name=\"print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: @Aamir Did you start the session at the top of page?

Comment: Yes at the very top of the page <?php
session_start(); ?>  i have a separate file for registering sessions which is included in this page

Comment: @Aamir  <?php echo session_start(); print_r($_SESSION); die;?> can you execute this and paste the result here.

Comment: Array ( [userid] => 1 [username] => aamirx64 [first_name] => [last_name] => [email_address] => ********

Comment: Now echo $_SESSION['username']; what does it print?

Comment: aamirx64
this is wat i want in the name field

Comment: <td><input type= class=\"form\" tabindex=\"1\" id=\"name\" name=\"name\" value=".$_SESSION['username']." /></td>

Comment: @Aamir check the comment posted above and replace the td where you want to show the username with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code on your page where you want to add name automatically.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
    $name=$_SESSION['name'];  // assign session to name variable
?>
```

write $name anywhere you want name to be displayed.

then edit your following line of code

```
   <td><input type= class=\"form\" tabindex=\"1\" id=\"name\" name=\"$name\" readonly=\"readonly\" /></td>
```

Comment: i have already registered a session with $username and i previously tried $username but its still not showing user name.

Comment: the logged in users while submitting their comment/post their username should automatically appear on comment just like Facebook, irrespective of typing their name manually in the name box..